# How do I output multiple lines from one line using awk

Tags: awk

My space delimited data looks like this:

```
Date Dollaramt timestamp person1 person2 person3 person4
```

I want to output it like this:

```
Date Dollaramt timestamp person1
Date Dollaramt timestamp person2
Date Dollaramt timestamp person3
Date Dollaramt timestamp person4
```

Also, not all lines have the same number of people.  How do I make it stop when it gets to the end of the line?

I have not tried any code yet, because I have not been able to find anything to try.  I learned awk yesterday.

I could do this is SAS!  But I need to learn how to do it in bash.

Comment: Please provide more details, such as an example of your dataset (with values, not just headers) and an example of the expected output

Comment: I don't know what SAS is but doing it in bash would be a bad idea (e.g. see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). You should do it in awk.

Answer (score 1):

Without an example dataset it's difficult to say how you can solve your problem, but perhaps this will help:

Example data:

```
cat test.txt
#>Date Dollaramt timestamp person1 person2 person3 person4
#>2021-06-28 4000 15:05 Yes No No No
#>2021-06-28 4200 15:06 No No Yes No
#>2021-06-28 4400 15:07 No No No Yes
```

Potential solution:

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {if($i == "Yes") print "Person " i-3 ":\t" $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3}}' test.txt
#>Person 1: 2021-06-28  4000    15:05
#>Person 3: 2021-06-28  4200    15:06
#>Person 4: 2021-06-28  4400    15:07
```

Example data:

```
cat test.txt
#>Date Dollaramt timestamp person1 person2 person3 person4
#>Date Dollaramt timestamp person1 person2 person3 person4 person5 person6
#>Date Dollaramt timestamp person1 person2 person3
```

Potential solution:

```
awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) {print $i "\t" $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3}}' test.txt
#>person1   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person2   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person3   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person4   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person1   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person2   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person3   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person4   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person5   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person6   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person1   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person2   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
#>person3   Date    Dollaramt   timestamp
```

Example data:

```
cat test.txt
#>2021-06-28 4000 15:05 Jenny Jane Frank Bill
#>2021-06-28 4000 15:05 Jared
#>2021-06-28 4200 15:06 Paul Fred Tony
#>2021-06-28 4400 15:07 Jesse Claire Nadia
```

Potential solution:

```
awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) {print $i "\t" $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3}}' test.txt
#>Jenny 2021-06-28  4000    15:05
#>Jane  2021-06-28  4000    15:05
#>Frank 2021-06-28  4000    15:05
#>Bill  2021-06-28  4000    15:05
#>Jared 2021-06-28  4000    15:05
#>Paul  2021-06-28  4200    15:06
#>Fred  2021-06-28  4200    15:06
#>Tony  2021-06-28  4200    15:06
#>Jesse 2021-06-28  4400    15:07
#>Claire    2021-06-28  4400    15:07
#>Nadia 2021-06-28  4400    15:07
```

If your data is in a different format, please edit your question to add further details.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for (i=4;i<=NF;++i) print $1, $2, $3, $i}' file
```

```
perl -lae 'print "@F[0..2,$_]" for 3..$#F' file
```

```
sed 's/ /\n/4;P;s/\(.*\) .*\n/\n\1 /;D' file
```

Comment: The awk line seem technically correct. But the answer lacks explanations. About what and why and how.
For advanced users, it is nice to have a comparison doing the same in awk, perl, sed,
But OP states he is a novice starting with awk. Awk is a good choice IMHO, I see no reason to divert.

Comment: @JürgenWeigert what explanation does the awk command need? Novice or not, what that script does is screamingly obvious.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank You!  Now I just need to study what all of this means so that I can add it to my knowledge base.